# Canvas draws once with translate and once without error

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I've taken nearly every possible countermeasure to prevent my program from drawing two dots instead of one on my chart. I want the dot in the middle to be shown, not the one in the top left. It seems to me the dot is being drawn once in the top left, matching the coordinates and everything, but then it draws a second dot with the `translate` method. Of course this is just speculation from what's happening on screen. The problem is occurring somewhere in the `draw()` function, `init()` function, or the `anim()` function - I can't pinpoint where the problem is.

```js
let graph = document.getElementById('chart');
let c = graph.getContext('2d');
graph.height = 754;
graph.width = 754;

function algebra() {

  xVertex = 2 * 10;
  yVertex = 5 * 10;

  let radius = 3;
  let node = [];


  function Node(xVertex, yVertex, radius) {
    this.r = radius;
    this.xV = xVertex;
    this.yV = yVertex;

    this.draw = function() {
      c.beginPath();
      c.arc(this.xV, this.yV, this.r, 0, Math.PI * 2, false);
      c.fillStyle = "red";
      c.fill();
      c.translate(377, 377);
      c.stroke();
      c.closePath();
    };

    this.update = function() {
      this.draw();

    };
  };

  function init() {
    node.push(new Node(xVertex, yVertex, radius));
    anim();
  };

  function anim() {
    requestAnimationFrame(anim);
    for (let i = 0; i < node.length; i++) {
      node[i].update(node);
    };
    c.clearRect(0, 0, graph.width, graph.height);
    console.log(node);
  };
  init();
};
```

```css
#graph {
  left: 100px;
  background-color: grey;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title> Proof of concept </title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div id="graph">
    <canvas id="chart"></canvas>
    <div id="y-axis"></div>
    <div id="x-axis"></div>
  </div>
  <div id="button" onclick="algebra()">
    <div id="btext">Calculate</div>
  </div>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I found your errors:

1) When you call `anim()` it must first clear the canvas and then redraw all points.

2) Call the next animation frame after all points are drawn on the canvas

And the main problem:

3) You are doing a translate of the canvas origin on each point drawn (and a large one (377, 377)). Since the origin is changing at every iteration or point drawn also the canvas section that is being erased is moving. The two points you got were the first and second iterarions, the others were offscreen.

What you need to do is translate the canvas origin to its middle only once, just after:

```
let c = graph.getContext('2d');
graph.height = 754;
graph.width = 754;

//Translate the origin to the canvas' center (do this only once)
c.translate(graph.width/2, graph.height/2);
```

If the canvas origin has moved to the center, then you must also erase the canvas from -width/2 to width/2 and height/2 to height/2. To do this you must use:

```
c.clearRect(-graph.width/2, -graph.height/2, graph.width, graph.height);
```

Just for **fun**, I've added three more points to the node array and adding a random number between -1 and 1 to each coordinate in every iteration. This results in a Brownian like motion simulation.

```js
let graph = document.getElementById('chart');
let c = graph.getContext('2d');
graph.height = 754;
graph.width = 754;

//Translate the origin to the canvas' center (do this only once)
c.translate(graph.width/2, graph.height/2);


function algebra() {

  //Changed to 0 to plot at center
  xVertex = 0;
  yVertex = 0;

  let radius = 3;
  let node = [];


  function Node(xVertex, yVertex, radius) {
    this.r = radius;
    this.xV = xVertex;
    this.yV = yVertex;

    this.draw = function() {      
      c.beginPath();
      c.arc(this.xV, this.yV, this.r, 0, Math.PI * 2, false);
      c.fillStyle = "red";
      c.fill();
      c.stroke();
      c.closePath();
    };

    this.update = function() {
      //this will generate random movement in x and y.
      this.xV += Math.random()*2-1;
      this.yV += Math.random()*2-1;
      this.draw();
    };
  };

  function init() {
    node.push(new Node(xVertex, yVertex, radius));
    node.push(new Node(xVertex, yVertex, radius));
    node.push(new Node(xVertex, yVertex, radius));
    node.push(new Node(xVertex, yVertex, radius));
    anim();
  };

  function anim() {
    //First clear the canvas then redraw
    c.clearRect(-graph.width/2, -graph.height/2, graph.width, graph.height);
    for (let i = 0; i < node.length; i++) {
      node[i].update(node);
    };
    //After all are drawn, call the next Animation Frame
    requestAnimationFrame(anim);
  };
  init();
};
```

```css
#graph {
  left: 100px;
  background-color: grey;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title> Proof of concept </title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div id="graph">
    <canvas id="chart"></canvas>
    <div id="y-axis"></div>
    <div id="x-axis"></div>
  </div>
  <div id="button" onclick="algebra()">
    <div id="btext">Calculate</div>
  </div>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Im concerned with some of this code, like where you said the origin resets after the node is drawn, because the program will draw parabolas on a graph when its finished. So I need the origin to be the same throughout the code.

Comment: If you want to have the center permanently translated to the middle of the canvas do it just after storing the getContext('2D') and never move it from there. But to clean the canvas you must draw a `clearRect(-width/2, height/2, width, height)`

Comment: If you are moving it after every point is drawn then the origin will keep drifting.

Comment: @MikhailYourchenko, I changed the answer in order to do the origin `translate()` only once.

Comment: @MikhailYourchenko please accept the answer if it solved your problem